# How to access the request in REST API

Tags: 8

I'm trying to follow the example of a custom rest api in https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/custom-rest-resources.

I don't understand how I can access the request for get or post. In the example there is only a default response, but I would of course like to make it depending on the request headers and body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only classes that extend `ResourceBase` implemented by Drupal core don't check/use what passed in the request. So I could not use Drupal core code as example.

If you really need to access any request value, and the argument passed to the `get()` or `post()` methods is not enough/adequate for your purpose, you can inject the request object in the `create()` static method.

```
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, array $serializer_formats, LoggerInterface $logger, Request $request) {
    parent:: __construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition,  $serializer_formats, $logger);
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration, 
      $plugin_id, 
      $plugin_definition, 
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'), 
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('rest'),
      $container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()
    );
  }
```

In the class methods you then use `$this->request` to access the request object.

Answer (score 2):

You can always get the current request through [`Drupal::request()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8.3.x):

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
```

Comment: Should this be injected?

Comment: Depends on context @Kevin, but yeah the `request_stack` service can be injected to accomplish the same thing